# How to open new page by URL with sending POST query?

Tags: java, http, post

I need from one JSP open another JSP, and send POST parameters to this JSP. I need to make same result as `response.sendRedirect(url);` but using this way I cant use POST request. Also note that I can't use `requestDispatcher` because this JSP in another context. I think I need to use something like this:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.somesite.com");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    ....
    writer.write(data);
```

But I'm not sure that I will open new page.

EDIT: @jaxb, yes, i tried it. But when I use it, I get only new page in existing page  (i.e. I change page1 to page2, but not open new one with sending POST data to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you need is a way to construct a valid HTTP Post Request. When I had a similar problem I found a httpclient library shared at http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/17679/1954 to be quite useful and simple to use. It exposes simple methods for setting your post request and then calling a post method to do the actual post. Everything is quite well explained in the article and I would recommend you to give it a try.

At the end of this article the author (Vlad Patryshev) says:

> Answer to the Eternal Question
>   Now you know how an HTML form (GET or POST) gets passed to the server as an HTTP request and how you can reproduce this behavior in your Java program—without overloading it with protocol details. You could say this solution answers the eternal question: How can one call a servlet or JSP from another servlet or JSP?

this I feel is quite similar to what you may be looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use the following code:

```
public static String postRequest(String targetURL, String postParams) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        // Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""
                + Integer.toString(postParams.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection
                .getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel the only solution is using sessions. set the POST parameters to the session in one jsp, send the 'redirect'  to the desired jsp and make it get your parameters from the session.

```
session.setAttribute("parameter","value");

//In the second jsp.
session.getAttribute("parameter");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have the client do the redirect using javascript to submit a form:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><%-- file: redirectToPage2.jsp  -  redirects to Page2.jsp sending all parameters with POST method --%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Redirecting... Please Wait.</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var submitform=function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(submitform,200);">
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="Page2.jsp" method="post">
<%
Map<String,String> params = request.getParameterMap();
Set<String> keys = params.keySet();
for(String key:keys)
{
    String val = params.get(key);
    %><input type="hidden" name="<%=key %>" value="<%=val %>"/><%
}
%>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```